# Expressão regular para URL com meio dinâmico

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, bash

Tenho um arquivos html com urls nesse padrão URL: `https://www.olympikus.com.br/tenis-olympikus-flower-415-feminino-cinza-D22-1131-010`
O padrão é `protocolo://dominio/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000`

Quero pegar todos os links nesse padrão. Então criei a seguinte ER: `(https\:\/\/?)www\.olympikus\.com\.br\/(.*)\-[A-Z0-9]{3}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{3}`

Infelizmente o padrão pega o techo inicial `protocolo://dominio/` e termina no ultimo casamento possível `-000-0000-000` Retornando uma string bruta no meio por causa do `(.*)`. Não consigo tratar a parte dinâmica da URL

Como escrever essa ER a fim de que ela retorne todos os links?

Atualmente estou a usar o egrep no terminal, mas exemplos com javascript são aceitos pois pretendo criar um crawler nessa linguagem no Nodejs.

Comment: Já. Da na mesma.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex

Esta seria a Regex: `((?:https|http|ftp)?:\/\/)?([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)(.*)`
Em que a [demo na Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/f0I6vw/1/) pode ser vista mais didaticamente.

### Código

#### Exemplo do Regex101

Retorna Grupo 2

```js
const regex = /((?:https|http|ftp)?:\/\/)?([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)(.*)/gm;
const str = `http://dominio.do/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000
https://www.olympikus.com.br/tenis-olympikus-flower-415-feminino-cinza-D22-1131-010
ftp://dominio.br/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000
dominio.c/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Exemplo SOen

Código de um usuário apagado que pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31941978/7690982)

Em que retorna a String Inteira

```js
var regex = /((?:https|http|ftp)?:\/\/)?([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)(.*)/g;

var input = `http://dominio.do/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000
https://www.olympikus.com.br/tenis-olympikus-flower-415-feminino-cinza-D22-1131-010
ftp://dominio.br/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000
dominio.c/strig-dinâmica-000-0000-000`;

while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    document.write(match[0] + "<br/>");
};
```

## Debug

O [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4zezq1WTxQ-oKL34) pode ser visto no link e ajuda na compreensão, em conjunto com a demo no Regex101.

## Explicação:

#### `((?:https|http|ftp)?:\/\/)?([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)(.*)`

- 1° Grupo de Captura - `((?:https|http|ftp)?:\/\/)?`

  - Quantificador `?` - Corresponde de zero a uma vez, tantas vezes quanto possível, devolvendo conforme necessário (*greedy*)
  - Grupo de não captura - `(?: Https | http | ftp)?`

    - Quantificador `?` - Corresponde de zero a uma vez, tantas vezes quanto possível, devolvendo conforme necessário (*greedy*)
    - Alternativas - `|` são as opções que estão entre o separador |, que age como um booleano `OR`.

      - 1º Alternativa - `https` corresponde aos caracteres https literalmente
      - 2ª Alternativa - `http` corresponde aos caracteres http literalmente
      - 3º Alternativa - `ftp` corresponde aos caracteres ftp literalmente
    - `:` corresponde ao caractere: literalmente
    - `\ /` corresponde ao caractere / literalmente
- 2° Grupo de Captura - `([^\/,\s]+\.[^\/,\s]+?)`

  - `[^\/,\s]+` - Corresponde a um caractere não presente no conjunto

    - Quantificador `+` - Corresponde entre uma e ilimitadas vezes, tantas vezes quanto possível, devolvendo conforme necessário (*greedy*)
    - `\ /` corresponde ao caractere / literalmente
    - `,` corresponde ao caractere , literalmente
    - `\ s` corresponde a qualquer caractere de espaço em branco (igual a [\ r \ n \ t \ f \ v])
  - `\.` Corresponde ao caractere . literalmente
  - `[^\/,\s]+?` - Corresponde a um caractere não presente no conjunto

    - Quantificador `+?` - Corresponde entre uma e ilimitadas vezes,  o menor número de vezes possível, expandindo conforme necessário (*lazy*)
    - `\ /` corresponde ao caractere / literalmente
    - `,` corresponde ao caractere , literalmente
    - `\ s` corresponde a qualquer caractere de espaço em branco (igual a [\ r \ n \ t \ f \ v])
- Positive Lookahead `(?=\/|,|\s|$|\?|#)`

  - Alternativas - `|` são as opções que estão entre o separador |, que age como um booleano `OR`.

    - 1a alternativa `\ /` corresponde ao caractere / literalmente
    - 2ª alternativa `,` corresponde ao caractere , literalmente
    - 3a alternativa `\ s` corresponde a qualquer caractere de espaço em branco (igual a [\ r \ n \ t \ f \ v])
    - 4ª alternativa `$` assegura a posição no final de uma linha
    - 5ª alternativa `\?` corresponde ao caractere ? literalmente
    - 6ª alternativa `#` corresponde ao caractere # literalmente
- 3° Grupo de Captura - `(.*)`

  - `. *` corresponde a qualquer caractere (exceto para terminadores de linha)
  - Quantificador `*` - Corresponde entre zero e ilimitado vezes, tantas vezes quanto possível, devolvendo conforme necessário (*greedy*)

> O segundo grupo é o que "interessa", em que este possui as
> informações desejadas dos links ou se desejar obter a string inteira, seria o grupo 0.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que a parte variável será composta por letras, número e o hífen, substitua o `(.*)` por `[a-z0-9\-]+` que deve resolver.